# what's the best term for this skill set

Tags: designers, terminology, adobe-certified-expert

I'm looking for the right word to use on my resume, that will be understood by the broadest possible range of people and won't look like I'm over-selling my skills (or under-selling them either).

I'm a freelancer who's done a lot of copyediting and ~2 years of newspaper page design. I totally enjoyed the design part and would like to add more of it to my work. I recently passed the Adobe Certified Expert exams for InDesign and Photoshop, upgraded my skills in Acrobat (a lot) and Illustrator (a little), and learned the basics of e-book formatting.

I'm not a brilliant artist, you wouldn't want me to design your annual report or museum catalog, but I can do simple design or implement someone else's more sophisticated design. So what do I call that? This may seem like a dumb question, but I have looked everywhere and asked everyone I can think of a good term.

Comment: Congratulations on adobe certification they say it all :)

Comment: If you are applying for very dissimilar positions, I'd have different versions of the resume, highlighting certain skills (but including all of them). And don't sell yourself short, those certifications are huge!

Answer (score 7):

I use "Production Artist," and then break out the specific skills (newspaper design, magazine layout, etc.).

Copyediting is an entirely separate skill, so list that on its own as "Proofreader" or "Copyeditor." And definitely highlight the Adobe Certification!

Comment: agreed that 'production artist' is the proper term.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. I started searching online under the term "production artist" and it looks just right. This was a big help and I am feeling really psyched now. Gracias!